# Are all varieties described by multi-linear equations rational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking at varieties of this form:

$$\sum_i^n \bigg(\prod_j^m  x_{i,j} \bigg) + K = 0$$

where $x_{i,j}, K \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there any way to tell if these varieties are rational (or not) in general?

Comment: What is the ambient space of this variety? The equation you wrote is not homogeneous in the variables, so it looks like it is affine. But then I do not understand the double indexing. Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: It is over the reals.  $x_{i,j}$ are just variables.  If you'd prefer, here is an example: $f_1 x + f_2 y + f_3 z + 7 = 0$, and I should mention that the $f_i$ as well as $x,y,z$ are variables.  So, for example, $x_{1,1} = f_1$, $x_{1,2} = x$ and so on

Comment: I've edited it to make a bit more sense.  In this case, n = 3, m = 2m $x_{2,1} = f_2$, $x_{2,2} = y$, $x_{3,1} = f3$, $x_{3,2} = z$, $K = 7$.  My apologies.  I just realized that it isn't as obvious as it is in my notes

Comment: I assume these are different variables. An equation of the form $xf(y)-g(z)=0$, where $x$ is one variable and $y,z$ are different set of variables always give a rational variety, since you can rewrite this as $x=g(z)/f(y)$.